# how to use open-sans font family to my Tamil website

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

I am going to develop a website in Tamil language using Photoshop and I wish to use open-sans font family to my website(Tamil language site), I already installed open-sans font family in my system but it not working on Tamil language text

Comment: "[Open Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans) is a humanist sans serif typeface designed by Steve Matteson, Type Director of Ascender Corp. This version contains the complete 897 character set, which **includes the standard ISO Latin 1, Latin CE, Greek and Cyrillic character sets.** Open Sans was designed with an upright stress, open forms and a neutral, yet friendly appearance. It was optimized for print, web, and mobile interfaces, and has excellent legibility characteristics in its letterforms." Doesn't mention Tamil.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementation, not design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search found a Droid Sans Tamil that night work for you. Google makes a don't Source Sans which is a nice free alternative to OpenSans or Helvetica. I'm not sure but guessing this is their Tamil implementation of that.

http://www.google.com/fonts/earlyaccess